# TypoScript Datapocessor seems not working if ContentElement is inserted as reference

Tags: typoscript, typo3-7.6.x

I've the following snippet from the TYPO3 Extension "bootstrap_package" which is available at TYPO3 Extension Repository.

```
dataProcessing {
    10 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\DatabaseQueryProcessor
    10 {
        table = tx_bootstrappackage_accordion_item
        where {
            data = field:uid
            intval = 1
            wrap = tt_content=|
        }
        orderBy = sorting
        dataProcessing {
            10 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\FilesProcessor
            10 {
                references.fieldName = media
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It's fetching records (Accordion items) from the table which belongs to the Accordion Content Element. Thats working fine. 
But when I insert somewhere in the page a reference to this Accordion, the records will not be fetched.

How this code needs to be changed so its working?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use it like this: (pidInList.field = pid << is missing)

```
tt_content.xy =< lib.default
tt_content.xy {
    templateName = CE_Stage
    dataProcessing {
        30 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\DatabaseQueryProcessor
        30 {
            table = tx_xy_slider
            pidInList.field = pid
            where {
                data = field:uid
                intval = 1
                wrap = tt_content=|
            }

            orderBy = sorting
            as = slides
            dataProcessing {
                10 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\FilesProcessor
                10 {
                    references.fieldName = image
                    as = images
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```